# How to sum list elements starting from a specific position

Tags: python

I have a list of lists such as:

```
mylist = [
    ['name', 'party', 'city', '0', '0', '1'],
    ['name', 'party', 'city', '1', '1', '1']
]
```

I want to compute the sum of the numbers starting from position 3. I know how to compute the sum of lis elements after converting the elements to int.

```
sum(int(mylist[i])) for i in range(len(mylist))
```

But how can I tell python to start summing from position 3 (where the numbers start?).

Comment: slice it: `somelist[3:]`

Comment: I tried to run your code and got a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list slicing:

```
mylist = [['name','party','city','0','0','1'],['name','party','city','1','1','1']]

print sum([sum(map(int, item[3:])) for item in mylist])  # prints 4
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit concise version

```
sum(int(nums) for inn in mylist for nums in inn[3:]) # 4
```